# LOCK/Password Protect home partition

Tags: linux, security, partition, hard-drive

I have access to a server with SSH and for some reason I want to LOCK/Password protect or encrypt the home partition.
Its very important for me to do it in the best possible way, I don't want anyone crack and access to that data unless I tell them the password or the way. (they have physical access to the server but I don't)
In the windows few years ago I installed a third party program which after I set a password with this program to a partition NO-ONE could get access to that without the password....
I'm looking for a similar program to do it in linux.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) works fine under Linux. And it's regarded as secure as long is your password is strong enough.

Answer (score 2):

The linux-native solution is [dmcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dm-crypt) and made easier through the use of [LUKS](http://code.google.com/p/cryptsetup/) and the `cryptsetup` tool. Each distribution has their own way of managing encrypted partitions, so the instructions do vary somewhat from one distro to another.